# F#: expected 'in' or other token error

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2013

So I've written a pretty simple program in F# that should sum all of the multiples of 3 and 5 below 1000:

```
[1..999]
|> List.filter (fun x -> x % 3 = 0 || x % 5 = 0)
|> let total = List.sum`
```

However, at the very end of the program I get the following error:

```
Unexpected end of input in expression. Expected 'in' or other token.
```

I am using the lightweight syntax, so I'm not sure why F# would want me to use an 'in' statement.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably intended to do this:

```
let total = 
  [1..999]
  |> List.filter (fun x -> x % 3 = 0 || x % 5 = 0)
  |> List.sum
```

The error message you are getting is because it expects a function after the forward pipe, you can have a let binding but as part of a function expecting at least one parameter.